# c++ openssl encryption fails sometimes

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

i want to encrypt and decrypt strings in my c++ appication and use openssl for that.
since i don't know exactly how to do it, i used this code from the internet:

```
        LPCTSTR encrypt(LPCTSTR inString, LPCTSTR inKey, LPCTSTR outString)
        {   
            const unsigned char* inStringC = (const unsigned char*)inString;
            const unsigned char* outStringC = (const unsigned char*)outString;
            const unsigned char* inKeyC = (const unsigned char*)inKey;

            HINSTANCE libeay32 = LoadLibrary("libeay32.dll");

            GET_FUNC_PTR(BF_set_key, void, void*, int, const unsigned char*);
            GET_FUNC_PTR(BF_cfb64_encrypt, void, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, long, void*, unsigned char*, int*, int);

            if (BF_set_key == NULL || BF_cfb64_encrypt == NULL) {
                TRACE("ERROR: failed while loading functions from \"libeay32.dll\"\n");
                return NULL;
            }

            BF_KEY key = {NULL, NULL};  
            BF_set_key(&key, strlen((const char*)inKeyC), inKeyC);

            size_t length = strlen(inString);
            unsigned char *cfb64_out = (unsigned char*)malloc((length+2)*sizeof(unsigned char*));
            unsigned char iv[32];
            memset(cfb64_out,0,length+1);
            memset(iv,0,32);
            int num = 0;    
            BF_cfb64_encrypt((unsigned char*)inStringC, cfb64_out, length, &key, iv, &num, BF_ENCRYPT); 
            FreeLibrary(libeay32);
            std::string retString = base64_encode((const char *)cfb64_out);
            strcpy((char*)outStringC, retString.c_str());
            free(cfb64_out);
            return outString;
        }

        LPCTSTR decrypt(LPCTSTR inString, LPCTSTR inKey, LPCTSTR outString)
        {
            const unsigned char* inStringC = (const unsigned char*)inString;
            const unsigned char* outStringC = (const unsigned char*)outString;
            const unsigned char* inKeyC = (const unsigned char*)inKey;

            HINSTANCE libeay32 = LoadLibrary("libeay32.dll");
            GET_FUNC_PTR(BF_set_key, void, void*, int, const unsigned char*);
            GET_FUNC_PTR(BF_cfb64_encrypt, void, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, long, void*, unsigned char*, int*, int);

            if (BF_set_key == NULL || BF_cfb64_encrypt == NULL) {
                TRACE("ERROR: failed while loading functions from \"libeay32.dll\"\n");
                return NULL;
            }


            BF_KEY key = {NULL, NULL};
            BF_set_key(&key, strlen((const char*)inKeyC), inKeyC);
            std::string retString = base64_decode((const char*)inStringC);

            size_t length = retString.length();
            unsigned char *cfb64_out = (unsigned char*)malloc((length+2)*sizeof(unsigned char));
            unsigned char iv[32];
            memset(cfb64_out,0,length+1);
            memset(iv,0,32);
            int num = 0;

            BF_cfb64_encrypt((unsigned char * )retString.c_str(), cfb64_out, length, &key, iv, &num, BF_DECRYPT);

            FreeLibrary(libeay32);

            strcpy((char *)outStringC, (char *)cfb64_out);
            free(cfb64_out);
            return outString;
        }
```

this works most times. but some times not.for example with the input "as" and the key "hfsa" it fails. since i am sure openssl is working i guess i did something wrong in calling the openssl functions. any ideas?

edit:
"it fails" means that either the encrypted string is empty or the decrypted string is empty. most times when it fails the decrypted string is only a substring of the expected.

edit2:
i isolated the problem to this: 
if i encrypt for example "sdg" with the key "dg" then the openssl function

```
                BF_cfb64_encrypt((char * )inputStr, cfb64_out, length, &key, iv, &num, BF_ENCRYPT);
```

return "ƒx" which has the length 2. 
when i decode that i have to tell the decrypt function of openssl (see above) the length to decrypt. this is 2. 
but the original string had length 3. so i get only "sd" as decryption result instead of "sdg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char* works differently within byte oriented encryption than for strings. Normally it holds null terminated strings. In this case it doesn't, it holds a byte array of definate length (3 in your case). The bytes in it can have any value *including* 00h, the null termination character, depending on the key, the data and the IV. So you just need to remember that (with CFB) your input lenght *is* your output length, and specify that particular length when decrypting (in other words, *you need to communicate the length* between the part that does the encryption and the part that does the decryption).